# Copy an IIS site from one server to another

Tags: asp.net, iis, migration, asp.net-mvc, deployment

We have an asp.net mvc web application deployed under IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. Now we need to move the web application to another server, which has IIS8 on Windows Server 2012.

Currently the asp.net mvc is deployed inside the defualt web application, and all the web application's folders and files can be found in this location :-

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

If i simply copy all the files and folder from the C:\inetpub\wwwroot and add them inside the same location on the new server, will it work?

Comment: Unlikely. 
More info needed, does it rely on a database? IIS8 is native to 2012, not IIS7

Comment: yes the two servers are integrated with the DB server,, also the DB server was not changed ,, we are only planning to move the application server not the DB server..

Comment: @DarkcatStudios is IIS8 work differently compared to IIS 7 ?

Comment: Well assuming all IIS settings, user permissions, file permissions etc are correct, the new server can access the DB, then its likely to work.
Is there any reason you cant just transfer everything and try it?

Comment: this what i am going to do

Comment: IIS7 and 8 do have differences yes - one is when you want to run something like PHP, you have to install it as a role.

Comment: no i am not using php, currently asp.net mvc is using the Defaultapplication pool with pipeline type = standard inside IIS7,, and i think this should work in IIS8 ? is this correct?

Comment: but inside IIS8 i did not find any application pool for (ASP.NET 4.0 or ASP.NET 4.0 classic) so this means that the .net 4.0 is not installed on the server,, is this correct?

Comment: Downvoted because little to no information was provided: for example, if your application relies on a database, you can't assume it will magically be transferred.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely to "Just work" but it is possible.

Often there will be settings, frameworks and user/folder permissions that cannot be transferred and will need to be set up manually on the new server.

Best advice is to pull everything over and try it, but make a Database backup first, just in-case.
If it doesnt work (which is likely) view error logs and browser errors to find the route causes (EG setting the correct .NET framework etc)

Also IIS7 and 8 deal with application pool identities slightly differently.

Comment: currently the asp.net mvc uses the "DefaultApplicationPool" with manage pipeline = standard inside IIS7 ,, so will this work on IIS8 ?